# Insert leads without mandatory values

Tags: csv, web2lead, data-import

Can we insert leads in Salesforce without mandatory values present in the record and also, we have to bulk insert records in salesforce without mandatory values.

Web-to-lead can insert leads without mandatory field values but how can we insert records in bulk(like a csv file) using web-to-lead process.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible validations on Lead Insert

1. Schema-defined required values - such as Lead.Company or any custom fields defined as Required in the metadata
2. Validation Rules you have coded on Lead
3. Trigger `.addError(...)` methods during before insert processing

Items 2 and 3 you can work around because the web-to-lead will use an integration user that you can detect using `$User` variables in #2 and `UserInfo.xxx()` methods in #3

However, for #1 the only workaround is for your before insert trigger to add missing values:

```
trigger defaultRequiredFields on Lead (before insert) {
  for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
     l.Company == String.isBlank(l.Company) ? '--not provided--' : l.Company;
     // next required field
  }
```